# How do I access the userid and password of a page using HTML Agility Pack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get started with HtmlAgilityPack and was wondering if someone could help me get off to a good start.

I'm trying to access the user1 id and the password1 id from the url https://www.foragentsonly.com/login.aspx

How would I go about that?

Comment: What part do you not know how to do?

Comment: I can get them by doing var user = doc.GetElementById("user1"); but is that the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have the HTML document already, this should work:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//input[@id=user1]");
doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//input[@id=password1]");
```

It just works off standard xpath syntax, so for more complex queries, use [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) as a guide.

Comment: And is it possible to select the image1 tag and submit the values?

Comment: To select the image1 tag, sure. Same thing, just modify the selector a bit. To submit the values - that's a different question, and has nothing to do with the agility pack. You'll need to create a web request, etc, for that.